# How to inject screen_on event? (not for beginners)

Tags: android, events, reflection, code-injection, sensors

I am trying to make sensors work when screen is off. It is well known bug. And there is no any soution for this on all phones. I have the hypothesis that i can can cheat kernel if I send(inject) screen_on event while actually the screen will be turned off. Do you have any ideas how can i check my hypothesis and inject such event?

There is some ways in Android to inject events http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=2640
In this case can help:
 1) Using of internal API. But i cant find API in sources witch i can use. Please help me with this.
 2) Direct event injection to /dev/input/eventX. But it seems that this is only input events such as keys but  i cant find there screen_off(screen_on) event.

Where can i find in sources of HAL the code where  screen_off event generated. I tried and did not find this code in sources.

Comment: Each Android device has a set very custom kernel drivers with custom power management and stuff that handles things like screen / sensor states. It might even be that case that the sensor voltage supply is hardwired to the screen voltage supply. I am pretty sure you can't inject some screen_on event that keeps the screen off but leaves the sensors alive.